# Is it possible to do a post save when a specific field on a model changes?

Tags: django, django-models

If it is possible to do a post save based on a field change, would the code look something like this? Note: I want a Car object to get created each time the address of the House model changes.

```
def create_car(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['??????']:
        car = Car.objects.filter(user=kwargs['instance'].user)

post_save.connect(create_car, sender=House.address)
```

I'm not sure what would go in the kwargs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare address fields in `pre_save` signal

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=House)
def create_car(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_instance = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        return

    if instance.address != old_instance.address:
        car = Car.objects.filter(user=kwargs['instance'].user)
        # todo
```